# The multi-part identifier "company.ID" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query breaks because I have a multipart identifier that could not be bound. I have searched around and have tried a few suggestions online and none of which work for me. I have made sure that there is no typing errors.

```
WITH TempResult AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RequestDate) as RowNum,
        [BillSearchesId],
        [RequestDate],
        company.[ID] AS [CompanyId],
        users.ID AS [UserID],
        [DeedsOffice], 
        [Description], 
        [DocNo],
        [MicrofilmRefNumber], 
        [UserReference],
        [USERNAME],
        [TextCopyRequest],
        [NotFound],
        STUFF ((SELECT ', ' + CAST([FormatId] AS VARCHAR(20))  
                FROM [dbo].[DeedsDocumentCopyLocations] ddcl 
                WHERE ddcl.DocumentCopyId = ddcr.DocumentCopyId 
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS [FormatsAvailable]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[DocumentCopyRequestsTable] ddcr
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[DocumentCopiesTable] ddc ON ddc.id = ddcr.DocumentCopyId
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[USERSTable] users ON users.ID = ddcr.UserId
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[COMPANYTable] company ON company.ID = ddcr.CompanyId
)
SELECT TOP (@LastRec-1) *
FROM TempResult
WHERE RowNum > @FirstRec
  AND company.ID = @companyID // The multi-part identifier "company.ID" could not be bound. 
  AND RowNum < @LastRec
  AND DocNo LIKE ISNULL(@DocumentNumber + '%',DocNo) 
  AND [Description] LIKE ISNULL(@Description + '%',[Description])
  AND UserReference LIKE ISNULL(@Reference + '%', UserReference)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you write `AND [CompanyId] = @companyID` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no table or table alias `Company` in that `SELECT` after your CTE - you cannot reference a table that isn't part of your `SELECT` ....

But that `company.ID` is available *from the CTE* already - just use that!

```
WITH TempResult AS
(
    SELECT 
        ....
        company.[ID] AS [CompanyId],  -- this defines a column "CompanyId" in your CTE
        ....
    FROM 
        ....
)
SELECT TOP (@LastRec-1) *
FROM TempResult
WHERE RowNum > @FirstRec
  -- use the "CompanyID" column from your "TempResult" CTE .....
  AND CompanyId = @companyID 
  ......
```